# Individually edit the width of TDs in an HTML table

Tags: html, css, width, html-table

How can I change the width of different TDs separately? Meaning, that if I change the width of a TD, the width of the column won't be affected, but only the row. For example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1unnb.png

How can I accomplish this? I've already tried altering the widths of each TD separately, however, when I do that, it changes the width of the entire column itself.

Here is the code of my table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Your Name" maxlength="20">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email Address:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email Address">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Message:</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="message" maxlength="500"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><center><img src="test.php" alt="" /></center></td></tr>
    <tr><td style="text-align:right">Enter the Code:</td><td><input id="security_code" name="security_code" type="text" placeholder="Enter the Code Above"/></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you're trying to do with tables. The whole idea of tables is that the `TD`'s stay aligned with respect to each other.

If you want to do this drop the use of tables and just use the label with the input element like this:

```
<label>Name: <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Your Name" maxlength="20"></label>
<label>Email Address: <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email Address"></label>
<label> Message: <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="message" maxlength="500"></textarea></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with embedding that into CSS?

```
.type_two{ width:50px; }
```

May have to fiddle with the code as well as `px` and `%` usage.

```
<td class="type_two">some type of text</td>
```